# Заполнение вложенного списка

Tags: c#, .net

У меня есть вложенный список и нужно его заполнить значениями возвращаемыми из функции. Что-то на подобии двумерной матрицы, где число строк равно длине одного списка, а число столбцов длине другого списка. Вопрос состоит в том как обратиться по индексу к элементам вложенного списка?

```
List<int> wordids;
List<int> hiddenids;
List<List<int>> inputWeights;

foreach (var wordid in wordids)
{
    foreach (var hiddeid in hiddenids)
    {
         inputWeights[wordid][hiddenid] = GetStrength(wordid, hiddenid);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

foreach перебирает массивы лишь на чтение.

Если хотите делать по-старинке, делайте так:

```
for (int wordIdx = 0; wordIdx < wordids.Count; wordIdx++)
    for (int hiddenIdx = 0; hiddenIdx < hiddenids.Count; hiddenIdx++)
        inputWeights[wordIdx][hiddenIdx] =
                          GetStrength(wordids[wordIdx], hiddenids[hiddenIdx]);
```

Возможно, вам нужно будет аллоцировать `inputWeights[wordIdx]`.

Я бы, однако, сделал с LINQ:

```
inputWeights =
    wordids.Select(wordid =>
        hiddenids.Select(hiddenid => GetStrength(wordid, hiddenid).ToList()
    ).ToList();
```

(Возможно, ещё более хорошей идеей было бы отказаться от материализированных списков, и избавиться от `.ToList()`).

Comment: Большое спасибо то что нужно.

Comment: @helio: пожалуйста!